# UK travel insurance for Indian green card holder with pre-existing medical conditions

Tags: indian-citizens, insurance, us-residents

My mother-in-law, who is an Indian citizen, is currently in the US, staying with my sister-in-law. She has a Green Card. My wife and I live in the UK and she is visiting us for a couple of months. How do we get a travel insurance for her that takes into account her pre-existing medical conditions (high blood pressure, diabetes)?

Searching for travel insurance in the UK seems to give only options that require the applicant be a UK resident (which my mil is not). Searching for travel insurance in India requires her to travel from India (which she is not).

I am unable to find a good site/provider that gives options for this scenario. Do you know any? All help will be appreciated!

Thanks,
Sridhar

Comment: You need to get her travel insurance from the USA which will cover her travels. She's a US resident. There are many insurance companies out there which will give you quotes.

Comment: In a weird case of search problems, I seem to get only results for US citizens or sites in the UK. Even if I explicitly move from google.co.uk to google.com, the results are the same. Is there a travel insurance comparison site in the US that you can share?

Comment: I just got several quotes from reputable companies like AIG and they have plans for people with preexisting conditions. https://www.insuremytrip.com/travel-insurance-plans-coverages/pre-existing-conditions/

Comment: Did you not get travel insurance 'traveling from India' when she left for the USA?

Comment: @user16259, since she has a Green Card, she has healthcare in the US, doesn't need travel insurance.

Comment: @user16259 From what I understand, a) it's not at all assured that any given American has health insurance, and b) it's not at all assured that any given US health insurance policy provides coverage outside the U.S.

Comment: You should check her US coverage to see if it is valid in the UK. It is not uncommon for US plans to have worldwide coverage.  You should also consider that plans that appear to be only for US citizens may actually cover permanent residents (read the fine print), but the people who write the promotional text for the web site may have failed to contemplate that possibility.

Comment: @jimmackenzie I had thought they were resident in India and on a trip encompassing the USA and UK but the op seems to indicate they are resident in the USA. I'm the former case, it would have made sense to get insurance from an Indian firm.

Comment: @user16259 A "green card holder" is someone who has permanent residence in the US. It is so named because the permanent residence cards used to be (and coincidentally are now again) green.